# How to get value of <td> if I know only the value of corresponding <th>?

Tags: python, html, parsing

I want to parse an HTML page using **Python** and pull a particular `<table>` out of there. Further, I want to get some specific values from that table.

The table consists of a bunch `<tr>`s, that look like this:

```
<tr>
<th class="align-left" scope="row"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:openPopup('https://www.website.com//webcontent/ap010098-etf-content/19.11.0/help/research/learn_er_glossary_1.shtml#dividendyield',420,450);return false;">Dividend Yield</a></th>
<td>3.35%</td>
</tr>
```

In this example I need to get the `3.35%`. The problem is, the only identifier I can see here is the text of the `<th>`, i.e. `Dividend Yield` in this case. ("class" is not unique)

How can I get the `<td>` value by addressing the `<th>` text value? Looked through a bunch of articles and tutorials, but none of them talk about this particular thing and I have just started learning Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With bs4 4.7.1 + you can use :contains to target the th by its text and then use an adjacent sibling combinator to get the adjacent td

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<tr>
<th class="align-left" scope="row"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:openPopup('https://www.website.com//webcontent/ap010098-etf-content/19.11.0/help/research/learn_er_glossary_1.shtml#dividendyield',420,450);return false;">Dividend Yield</a></th>
<td>3.35%</td>
</tr>
'''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('th:contains("Dividend Yield") + td').text)
```